# Threads waiting for the last one to notify them

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I want the threads to wait until last one uses br and notifies the other                                                          threads. But it gets stuck entering first `wait()`,what am i missing?

```
public class CrawlerThread implements Runnable {
private BufferedReader br;
private FileHandler fileHandler;
private File sourceFile;
private String skillString;
private Map<String, String> urlData = new HashMap<String, String>();
private String urlFirst = Initializer.urlFirst;

public static Integer threadCount = 0;

public CrawlerThread(BufferedReader br, FileHandler fileHandler,
        File sourceFile, String skillString, Map<String, String> urlData) {
    this.br = br;
    this.fileHandler = fileHandler;
    this.sourceFile = sourceFile;

    this.skillString = skillString;
    this.urlData.putAll(urlData);
    new Thread(this).start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("!!!!");

    String companyName;
    String searchString;
    SearchObject searchObject = new SearchObject();
    try {String c;
        while ((c=br.readLine())!=null && c.equalsIgnoreCase("Company Name")) {
            try {
                if ((companyName = br.readLine().trim()) != null) {
                    if (threadCount == (Initializer.MAX_THREAD - 1)) {
      synchronized(br){
                        System.out.println("++");
                        br.close();
                        br.notifyAll();}

                    } else
                        try {
                            System.out.println("**" + threadCount);
                            synchronized (br) {
                                synchronized (threadCount) {
                                    threadCount++;
                                }
                                br.wait();
                            }
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Comment: By far not enough information. What are `br` and `threadCount`, how is this called and executed, etc. But you might want to have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html - this is created for exactly this purpose.

Comment: My guess is that your threads are not synchronized on the same br instance which causes notifyAll() fail to behave as you'd expect

Comment: Your first problem is that you aren't testing the result of readLine() for null before doing anything else with it. Until you fix that your code can't really be taken seriously.

Comment: dude...i am no batman

Comment: silly mistake again...br.readline().equals company name only for first thread

Answer (score 0):

To use wait/notify, both threads should acquire the shared lock and both check for a condition and modify if necessary, if you are certain there will be only 1 thread waiting the `notify()` is OK, if not then use `notifyAll()`, basically the waiting thread should be like like:

Sample waiting thread condition:

```
synchronized(lock){
  while(!condition){
    lock.wait();
  }
}
```

Sample notifier thread:

```
synchronized(lock){
  condition=true;
  lock.notifyAll();
}
```

You could also use a `CountDownLatch`:

```
final CountDownLatch latch=new CountDownLatch(1);
```

Waiting thread:

```
public void waitForCondition(){
  latch.await();
}
```

Notifier thread:

```
public void notifyWaitingTreads(){
  latch.countDown();
}
```

Comment: give answer to the question